# Disconnecting lambda functions in Qt5

Tags: c++, lambda, qt5

Is it possible to disconnect a lambda function? And if "yes", how?

According to https://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax I need to use a `QMetaObject::Connection` which is returned from the QObject::connect method, but then how can I pass that object to the lambda function?

Pseudo-code example:

```
QMetaObject::Connection conn = QObject::connect(m_sock, &QLocalSocket::readyRead, [this](){
    QObject::disconnect(conn); //<---- Won't work because conn isn't captured

    //do some stuff with sock, like sock->readAll();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried that? (But also add `conn` to the capture list for the lambda)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, it segfaults for some reason. As soon as I remove the QMetaObject::Connection conn and leave only the code after the = the segfault dissapears.

Comment: The problem is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847507/qt5-new-signal-to-lambda-connections-memory-leak

Comment: @kfunk I did see that question, but I can't get any conclusion of it. Can you explain a little bit further how and why could it be done?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you capture `conn` directly, you're capturing an uninitialised object by copy, which results in undefined behaviour.  You need to capture a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<QMetaObject::Connection> pconn{new QMetaObject::Connection};
QMetaObject::Connection &conn = *pconn;
conn = QObject::connect(m_sock, &QLocalSocket::readyRead, [this, pconn, &conn](){
    QObject::disconnect(conn);
    // ...
}
```

Or using a shared pointer, with slightly greater overhead:

```
auto conn = std::make_shared<QMetaObject::Connection>();
*conn = QObject::connect(m_sock, &QLocalSocket::readyRead, [this, conn](){
    QObject::disconnect(*conn);
    // ...
}
```

From Qt 5.2 you could instead use a context object:

```
std::unique_ptr<QObject> context{new QObject};
QObject* pcontext = context.get();
QObject::connect(m_sock, &QLocalSocket::readyRead, pcontext,
    [this, context = std::move(context)]() mutable {
    context.reset();
        // ...
 });
```

Comment: Could you please explain the first example in more detail? Why do you create pointer, then reference to the pointer and pass both to the lambda?

Edit:
Isn't it possible to do something like:
    *pconn = QObject::connect(...);
end leave the conn completely out of it?

Comment: In the first example, the lifetime of `conn` is determined by the code block, while the lambda function still uses it.  Sheer luck if `conn` is still alive.  In this scenario, you definitely need a `shared_ptr<Connection>`.

Comment: @xtofl `conn` in the first example is a reference; its lifetime is the lifetime of the `unique_ptr`, which is captured into the lambda. (This should be a C++14 init-capture, really.)

Comment: Note that since Qt 5.2 there is also an overload that takes a context object. The connection will then be disconnected when the sender or the context object is destroyed.

Comment: @PredragManojlovic, `context` is of type `unique_ptr<>`. By doing `context.clear()`, the `unique_ptr` is deleted. However, I am still not clear, why the simple `QObject` is referred as "context" object. It seems to be a mechanism and not some type.

Comment: @iammilind `clear` is not a member of `std::unique_ptr`. `release` deletes the pointer. `context` is simply a synchronization object. By connecting the slot to the this instance and deleting it in the handler, Qt automatically also releases the signal-slot connection. Qt does this for all connections, if the receiver is deleted.

Comment: This code seems not tested .. and likely not working.

Comment: A little late to the party, but `release` of `unique_ptr` relinquishes ownership to the caller, meaning you are now responsible for deallocating the context object manually (potentially with `deleteLater`). What you were probably looking for is `context.reset()`

Answer (score 11):

The context solution from ecatmur's answer is the easiest option, but I think the use of the smart pointer makes it hard to understand. I prefer to use a raw pointer instead:

```
QObject *context = new QObject(this);
connect(sender, &Sender::signal, context, [context] {
  delete context;
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Qt 6 added the `Qt::SingleShotConnection` connection type. If the intention is to unconditionally disconnect after the first call (and not to disconnect based on some other condition), then this would work:

```
connect(sender, &Sender::signal, context, [] {
  // ...
}, Qt::SingleShotConnection);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `conn` as a private variable in the .h file. `QMetaObject::Connection conn`. 
in the lambda function, you can use `conn` and disconnect it.

```
 conn = QObject::connect(m_sock, &QLocalSocket::readyRead, [=](){
    QObject::disconnect(conn); //<---- Won't work because conn isn't captured

    //do some stuff with sock, like sock->readAll();
}
```