# Will a disconnect() called on a particular `QObject::Signal()` will disconnect lambda automatically?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qobject, disconnect

Suppose, there is a lambda connected to a `signal` as below:

```
connect(pObject, &Object::mySignal, [] () { lambda; });
```

Will below statement disconnect the lambda automatically?

```
disconnect(pObject, &Object::mySignal, nullptr, nullptr);
```

I am asking this, because in the [`QObject::disconnect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect)'s documents there are 2 contradicting statements:

> **2** Disconnect everything connected to a specific signal:
> `disconnect(myObject, SIGNAL(mySignal()), nullptr, nullptr);`

and

> Note: It is **not possible** to use this overload **to disconnect** signals connected to **functors or lambda expressions**. That is because it is not possible to compare them. Instead, use the overload that takes a QMetaObject::Connection`

Related: [Disconnecting lambda functions in Qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828678/disconnecting-lambda-functions-in-qt5)

Comment: This seems fairly easy to test. Have you tried it?

Comment: @JarMan, not really. We are facing some undefined behaviour related to `QSslSocket` in our code on random basis. So now we are investigating all the signal/slots one by one. We are not sure, why the crash happens, but this is one of the topmost suspicions.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, the two quotes you gave are in fact from different `QObject::disconnect` overloads.

In summary, the call...

```
disconnect(myObject, &MyObject::mySignal, nullptr, nullptr);
```

**should disconnect everything connected to the `MyObject::mySignal`** signal of the `MyObject` instance pointed to by `myObject` -- including lambdas/functors.

I think the perceived contradiction comes from the fact that the second statement (the "Note") is rather badly worded.  What it should state is...

> **Note**: It is not possible to use this overload to disconnect signals connected to ***specific*** functors or lambda expressions. ...

Hence, given the 'mocked up' code...

```
QPushButton *pb = ...
auto slot = [](bool checked) { /* Some useful stuff. */ };
connect(pb, &QPushButton::clicked, this, slot);
```

it is not then possible to do...

```
disconnect(pb, &QPushButton::clicked, this, slot);
```

If, however, you do as the quote says and...

> ...use the [disconnect] overload that takes a `QMetaObject::Connection`

then the following should work...

```
auto connection = connect(pb, &QPushButton::clicked, this, slot);
disconnect(connection);
```

[**Note**: I don't have `Qt` installed on the box, so the above is untested.]